# Removal accent with apache solr

Tags: apache, search, solr, schema

I'm trying to make a search with apache solr using this scheme http://pastie.org/5114389 but when I type "josé" the file is found but when I write "jose" I do not get the result.

Efetuei searching the internet for an answer and had to use the class  but when I insert makes no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see from your schema that you are using the `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` already on your `text` fieldType that is assigned to the `default` field. However, it is only being applied to the indexing of that field. I would suggest that you also apply it to the querying of your field as well, to ensure that your query terms are being folded to match the items in the index. Typically, in a case like this when you add a filter factory to the indexing you would also add it to the querying so that query terms and index terms are all being converted/compared appropriately.

So I would modify your schema to the following:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" words="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" words="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: There was also tested in this way, but I found that did not work. I noticed that someone else managed to solve it. http://www.bitabit.eng.br/2011/03/16/sunspot-solr-how-to-sort-accented-fields/ I applied the same rules used by him, but still to no avail.

Comment: We use the ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory today and it solves the same issue.Might be the use of the `words="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"` as I think this limits what words are being folded. Try removing that setting or adding jose to the list...

Comment: Still could not, as the word may be other José words like João, Cláusula, Decisão... etc.

Comment: Understood. My only remaining guess is that this term is coming from the Subject field which is defined as `fieldType="string"` Are you searching against the Subject field directly and not the default field. Also what happens if you change Subject to be `fieldType="text"`. Note that you will need to reindex your data after making schema changes for those new rules/filters, etc. to be applied.